# IndexError: index out of range in self ( Google Colab notebook ) while implementing Roberta Pretrained Model

Tags: python, sentiment-analysis, vader, roberta-language-model

```
res = {}
for i, row in tqdm(df.iterrows(), total=len(df)):
    try:
        text = row['text']
        myid = row['id']
        vader_result = sia.polarity_scores(text)
        vader_result_rename = {}
        for key, value in vader_result.items():
            vader_result_rename[f"vader_{key}"] = value
        roberta_result = polarity_scores_roberta(text)
        both = {**vader_result_rename, **roberta_result}
        res[myid] = both
    except RuntimeError:
        print(f'Broke for id {myid}')
```

I tried using loading Roberta model first , also tried checking if the text variable is longer than 512 tokens. But it does not work.

Comment: in what line did the error happen?

Comment: roberta_result = polarity_scores_roberta(text) -  this line

Comment: then i assume the issue is internal, but it is caused by the variable ```text```, try printing the variable text, and check if there's any issues you're noticing with the output. if there's none, then test out the ```polarity_scores_roberta``` function and see at what number does it crash.

if all of those fail, or  ```polarity_scores_roberta``` crashes at every int you give it, then the issue might be inside their code, or the function doesn't require the type of row['text'] but instead a different value. in that case, try looking through the docs and find what input does the function need.

Comment: Actually , it is giving error after it completed 21% 103/500 broke for id 103 everytime

Comment: so, the issue is with that specific text. just try debugging it using your ide and find out what value does it have that made it crash

Comment: thank u so much @oriraisfeld but i didn't understand how to check value and what to do after that

Comment: oh yeah, sorry, most IDEs nowdays have something called debugging mode, it allows you to stop the code at any point and check the values of every variable currently existing. idk what kind of IDE are you using, but i'm assuming pycharm (since most people use pycharm), [this video](https://youtu.be/sRGpvbhOhQs?si=Skqfxobg5Pcw04uz) explains well what i mean

Comment: actually i am running code in google colab notebook , is it possible to debug in colab

Comment: there's the %debug mode in google collab, i don't use it a lot, so idk how to use it, but i did find  [this video](https://youtu.be/rSPyvPw0p9k?si=GAv4aLzNpzl3GBHt) which explains it in like 3 minutes